# How do I create a multidimensional array from a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reserveid] => 12
            [description] => description 
            [amount] => 1000
            [startdate] => 2020-01-01 00:00:00
            [catid] => 8
            [catname] => child categoryname
            [parentid] => 3
            [parentname] => parent categoryname
        )
```

A reserve belongs either to a child category or directly to a parent category.

I want to create an array where all the parents are grouped together. After that all the childs are grouped together and than all the reserves are grouped together.

So I need a array like this:

```
parentid -> catid -> reserveid -> (description, amount, startdate)
```

I'm quite new to programming and I learned that arrays are the thing for this, but I can't wrap my head around the procedure. Could someone guide me through this way of thinking? I would very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop on the elements of your array, and create a new array whose keys will be the values you retrieve.

```
$array = [
    ['parent' => 10, 'cat' => 5, 'reserve' => 1, 'foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'bar'],
    ['parent' => 8, 'cat' => 3, 'reserve' => 1, 'foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'bar'],
    ['parent' => 10, 'cat' => 5, 'reserve' => 1, 'foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'bar'],
];
$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $newArray[$arr['parent']][$arr['cat']][$arr['reserve']] = [
        'foo' => $arr['foo'],
        'bar' => $arr['bar']
    ];
}
var_export($newArray);
```

Comment: This one worked like a breeze, but has one mayor flaw for me. When I have things directly under a parent category and also things under its child categories, I get them seperatly.